# css display specified part of image in bottom right corner of a canvas

Tags: css

I want to display an image in a div.

I want to display the bottom-right part of the image. e.g.

```
<div id="sample">
</div>

#sample
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: url('image-url') no-repeat;
    background-position: -100px -100px;
}
```

And display the image in the bottom-right corner of the canvas. e.g.

```
<div id="sample">
<img src="image-url" /> 
</div>

#sample
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

So, how to combine them together - display bottom-right part of an image in the bottom-right corner of a canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
```

to your rules of the div #sample